# Apache VirtualHost and localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost

I'm working with XAMPP on Mac OS X.

I'm trying to run a [Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) website properly for a client, and I really don't know Symfony (yet). I just want to install and launch it.

I've changed my *[/etc/hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))* file this way:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mysite.local
```

And the *httpd.conf* file this way:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.local
  DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/web
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  Alias /sf /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the site is working (yay!), but I can't access any more any of my other local sites because **localhost** is rendered as **[www.mysite.local](http://www.mysite.local)**.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is normal if you see it. Since it is the first virtual host entry, it will show local host.

Let’s say for example you didn't want that page to show. All you want to show is the "Apache, it works" page, so you would make a *vhost* entry before mysite.local as local host and point it to the "it works" page.

But this is normal. I had this problem before, so don't worry!

Comment: Ok, i've added a VirtualHost for localhost also after the first directive, and now it works. Thank you :)

Comment: No Problem :) thats what im here for!

Comment: @AngelicaRosa Can You direct the step vy step answer, how you solved your problem. I'm unable to create virtualhost for localhost.

Comment: @Siraj just look at the answer with 74 upvotes, there's the virtualhost code you have to use.

Answer (score 130):

This worked for me!

To run projects like `http://localhost/projectName`:

```xml
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
   ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot path/to/htdocs/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

To run projects like `http://somewebsite.com` locally:

```xml
<VirtualHost somewebsite.com:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /path/to/htdocs/somewebsiteFolder
     ServerName www.somewebsite.com
     ServerAlias somewebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The same for other websites:

```xml
<VirtualHost anothersite.local:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /path/to/htdocs/anotherSiteFolder
     ServerName www.anothersite.local
     ServerAlias anothersite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer. No port swaps, just how the OP imagined.

Comment: Thanks, great! That helped me. Also I would say that if one wants to run projects like 'projectname.com', he needs to add 'projectname.com' to `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on Ubuntu)

Comment: but this configurations cannot be use at the same time?

Comment: In the first example where should I write projectName (in Apache configuration file)?

Comment: very effective and an alternate way to Bind9 wich is a little complicated way of having your in-house DNS

Comment: and how does /etc/hosts look?
and does this work when document rot is outside /var/www?

Comment: @ganatra Your the man.... Finally i can successfully set up "virtual hosts". CHAPTER closed.

Comment: After adding `somewebsite.com` to the `/etc/hosts` file, I also had to [make Chrome stop redirecting to https](https://superuser.com/a/881431/573965)

Comment: Why are you placing the servername in `<VirtualHost>` tag? Why not keep it `*:80`?

Answer (score 32):

`localhost` will always redirect to `127.0.0.1`. You can trick this by naming your other VirtualHost to other local loop-back address, such as `127.0.0.2`. Make sure you also change the corresponding `hosts` file to implement this.

For example, my `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this:

```xml
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/6. App Data/XAMPP Shared/htdocs/intranet"
    ServerName intranet.dev
    ServerAlias www.intranet.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/intranet.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/intranet.dec-access.log" combined

    <Directory "D:/6. App Data/XAMPP Shared/htdocs/intranet">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(Notice that in `<VirtualHost>` section I typed `127.0.0.2:80`. It means that this block of VirtualHost will only affects requests to IP address `127.0.0.2` port `80`, which is the default port for HTTP.

To route the name `intranet.dev` properly, my `hosts` entry line is like this:

```
127.0.0.2 intranet.dev
```

This way, it will prevent you from creating another VirtualHost block for `localhost`, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Using other local loop-back address is a very neat trick. Kudos!

Comment: Pro tip: Don't forget to change the `Listen` parameter in your `httpd.conf` to match your configured loopback addresses.

Comment: Yes! this using 127.0.0.2 (or .3 or .4, etc.) did the trick for me for testing sites on my local machine (Win 10, Apache, PHP7.2) which also use .htaccess Rewrite rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You may want to use this:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "somepath\Apache2.2\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

as your first virtual host (place it before other virtual hosts).

Comment: That fixed the issue for me on Mavericks

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04!

Comment: Worked for me, you fantastic soul!

Comment: Worked for me too. Even though your answer is just like a repetition of other answers above. But I did exactly you did and it worked. 
Thanks a bunch

Comment: Mavericks = [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks)

Answer (score 11):

Additional description for [John Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981174/apache-virtualhost-and-localhost/17517799#17517799) [from the official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). To understand why it is.

> **Main host goes away**
>
> **If you are adding virtual hosts** to an existing web server, you must
> also **create a  block for the existing host**. The
> ServerName and DocumentRoot included in this virtual host should be
> the same as the global ServerName and DocumentRoot. List this virtual
> host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the
> default host.

For example, to work properly with XAMPP, to prevent VirtualHost overriding the main host, add the follow lines into file *httpd-vhosts.conf*:

```xml
# Main host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

# Additional host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Other directives there
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't use `ServerName localhost`, just copied (from httpd.conf)   `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory` parts and it worked fine - same as previously with all hosts except the `ServerName`s and `Alias`es in the lower `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag.

Comment: that definitely helps, thank you :D :D 
now I can use both localhost and custom virtual host

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue of accessing localhost while working with virtualHost. I resolved it by adding the name in the virtualHost listen code like below:

In my **hosts** file, I have added the below code (**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**) -

```
127.0.0.1   main_live
```

And in my **httpd.conf** I have added the below code:

```xml
<VirtualHost main_live:80>
    DocumentRoot H:/wamp/www/raj/main_live/
    ServerName main_live
</VirtualHost>
```

That's it. It works, and I can use both **localhost**, **phpmyadmin**, as well as **main_live** (my virtual project) simultaneously.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @Raj

Comment: Modifying hosts file is important here.

Comment: In my case, hitting main_live on browser did not work for the first time. then I tried http://main_live, it worked. then main_live (without http) started working. Very strange

Comment: @Vohidjon Karimjonov : I think there is browser access permissions needed to work this. So may be you have permitted browser to listen request for "main_live" and then only it starts working as a website, else it is considered as just a keyword. So when you inserted http://main_live it looked for the host file  for the entry of 'main_live' and if found then only browser will ask you for permissions, and if permission granted then you will get your virtual host working and loads your homepage of web application. Let it be it worked for you. that's great!!!

Answer (score 5):

For someone doing everything described here and still can't access:

XAMPP with Apache 2.4:

In file *httpd-vhost.conf*:

```xml
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/dir"
    ServerName something.dev
   <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/dir">
    Require all granted #apache v 2.4.4 uses just this
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There isn't any need for a port, or an IP address here. Apache configures it on its own files. There isn't any need for NameVirtualHost *:80; it's deprecated. You can use it, but it doesn't make any difference.

Then to edit hosts, you must ***run [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) as administrator*** (described below). If you were editing the file without doing this, you are editing a pseudo file, not the original (yes, it saves, etc., but it's not the real file)

In Windows:

**Find the Notepad icon, right click, run as administrator, open file, go to *C:/WINDOWS/system32/driver/etc/hosts*, check *"See all files"*, and open hosts.**

If you were editing it before, probably you will see it's not the file you were previously editing when not running as administrator.

Then to **check if Apache is reading your httpd-vhost.conf**, go to folder *xampFolder/apache/bin*, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right click, open a terminal command here, open XAMPP (as you usually do), start Apache, and then on the command line, type `httpd -S`. You will see a list of the virtual hosts. Just check if your *something.dev* is there.

Answer (score 3):

According to this documentation: [Name-based Virtual Host Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html)

You may be missing the following directive:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: I've added the directive, but nothing change: when i open http://localhost/ i see the site configured as http://www.mysite.local.

Answer (score 3):

Just change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>`.

Then the default `DocumentRoot` will serve for all domains or IP addresses that point to your server and specified `VirtualHost` will work.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because your web folder (as mentioned "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/**web**") is empty.

My suggestion is first to make your project and then work on making the virtual host.

I went with a similar situation. I was using an empty folder in the **DocumentRoot** in **httpd-vhosts.confiz** and I couldn't access my **shahg101.com** site.

Comment: may is not a clear answer, help using exact solution

Comment: Virtual drive will not be created unless u have INDEX.php in the folder, so I was saying that your folder may be empty (containing no index.php  file)

Answer (score 0):

I am running [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus). This is what worked for me:

1. Open up a terminal and *cd* to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. There
   you will find a file called `000-default.conf`.
2. Copy that file: `cp 000-default.conf example.local.conf`
3. Open that new file (I use [Nano](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20Nano); use what you are comfortable with).
4. You will see a lot of commented lines, which you can delete.
5. Change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost example.local:80>`
6. Change the document root to reflect the location of your files.
7. Add the following line: `ServerName example.local` And if you need to, add this line: `ServerAlias www.example.local`
8. Save the file and restart Apache: `service Apache2 restart`

Open a browser and navigate to `example.local`. You should see your website.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Windows and the [Bitnami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitnami#Technology_overview) [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) Stack Manager Tool this virtual host configuration should go into `Bitnami\apache2\conf\bitnami\bitnami.conf`

Note: Some settings in **Directory** section is not a must.

For example, my virtual host configuration for **site.com** would be as follows:

```xml
<VirtualHost site.com:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/apache2/htdocs/site/docroot"

  <Directory "C:/Bitnami/apache2/htdocs/site/docroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember that configuration for vhost as mentioned, by other friends, [sagits's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719971/7995302) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

On Apache 2.4 on Windows, you also have to include the vhosts file from httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```