# After adding vhosts definiation xamppfiles/htdocs is invisible on http , but still accessible through https

Tags: macos, apache, vhosts

I have vhost like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>        
    ServerName  local.testing.com    
     DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Sites/myapp"  
    DirectoryIndex index.html
     <Directory /Users/myname/Sites/myapp>   
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

***hots files***

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   local.testing.com
::1             localhost
```

after enabling this vhost , i am unable to access any of the sites under xampp/htdocs through http. But they are accessible through https

when I access localhost it shows directory listing for :`"/Users/myname/Sites"`

plz help me sort out this issue ,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue was that we need a **virtual host** for **localhost** e. g [like this SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981174/apache-virtualhost-and-localhost)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
   ServerAlias localhost
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```