# How to access xampp server?

Tags: php, xampp, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I installed XAMPP server in a rackspace cloud server. Now I want to access it from my local PC, like accessing web server through IP and coding &  executing. Any solution would be grateful received.

Comment: This could be helful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to remote server from local machine, then
you can use PuTTY - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Here is a brief tutorial on how to use it: 
http://www.gamexe.net/other/beginner-guide-ssh/

or you can search for another one.

There are many articles about PuTTY.

Answer (score 1):

How about using FTP to write your code and execute. I work directly off my server I use Netbeans as my IDE of choice and it has a ftp feature that lets you work with files directly off your server.

Is that what you meant when you wrote:

> web server through IP and coding & executing