# Creating Multiple Virtual Hosts on xampp apache server v-3.2.1 on windows-10

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am tried to create Multiple Virtual Hosts on my Windows 10, 64-bit, XAMPP 3.2.1
I did the following:

1- **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

I have added these line at the bottom of the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 smc
127.0.0.1 ocms
```

2- **D:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf**

Virtual hosts is already is enabled see the following:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

3- **D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

Here i have added the following code block on httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName smc
    DocumentRoot "D:/vhosts/smc"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "D:/vhosts/smc/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ocms
    DocumentRoot "D:/vhosts/ocms/"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "D:/vhosts/ocms">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally i have put both my directories in my D:/vhosts/ folder:

```
D:/vhosts/ocms
D:/vhosts/smc
```

After i have restarted my apache server and test the url like:

```
http://ocms
```

Or

```
http://smc
```

It returns the following error:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
ocms
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
```

I have googled it too many times for last three to four days and also followed some other posts on stackoverflow i.e. [how to create virtual host on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp) but with no luck. Please let me know what i am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have done it. i had to put all my directories under the htdocs folder like this.
structure should be:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs
D:\xampp\htdocs\test\smc
D:\xampp\htdocs\test\ocms
```

Thank you all for your precious time

Answer (score 0):

**Your initial settings works** fine for me.

I think your problem was that the index was missing.

This line will force Apache to accept only **index.php** file as entry point:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

However, if your entry point has a different name or extension you get the error:

```
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protecte
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps in Windows 11 64 bit home edition, XAMPP version 8.2.12 and PHP version 8.3.2 as on February 13, 2024. And at first, i got the error that XAMPP apache was not running. Then i changed the backslashes in DocumentRoot to Forwardslashes. Then i was able to start the apache server without any problem.

- Now when i click on Admin, browser opens up with localhost with all my projects related to web development and php websites.
- And when i enter 'http://example.com' in my web browser. One of my projects in localhost opens up successfully. Thanks for the information. It greatly helps. Well written.