# XAMPP / WP localhost loads one website fine, but Connection Reset on second

Tags: wordpress

I am running the latest XAMPP and Wordpress on my Windows 10 machine, and everything has been working fine for more than a week. I run two websites under XAMPP/htdocs, web1 and web2. This morning Chrome said Connection Reset for web2.

localhost/dashboard loads the XAMPP page correctly.
localhost/web1 loads web1 correctly.

From this I conclude that XAMPP, Apache, WP, and MySql are all working correctly, for web1.

But for some reason Chrome and IE get Connection Reset errors on web2.
I can't log into the wp-admin screen on web2 either.

I've looked for solutions on the net, emptied browser caches, etc, and even did a 'netsh winsock reset' on the whole computer, but with no success.

I think it's something wrong with wordpress on website 2, because web1 works fine, right beside web2. Does anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? I may end up reinstalling wordpress and all my plugins, etc.

Here's my apache error log. Not sure if these errors are relevant, because they are in the log when everything was working fine, too.

`[Sat Oct 29 09:11:23.875588 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH00428: Parent: child process 16144 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.084459 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.105497 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.105497 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7 2016 11:13:22
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.105497 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Users\\jameson\\Documents\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Users/jameson/Documents/XAMPP/apache'
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.106499 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 17048
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.477157 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 17048:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.563811 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 17048:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:24.585366 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17048:tid 500] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 29 09:11:25.869511 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 528] AH00428: Parent: child process 17048 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought of that. I updated my post, but I'm not sure the errors are relevant. I can't see anything about web2 in the logs, anywhere. Thank you for your interest. This kind of thing must be very boring to anyone who knows what's going on.. :-)

Comment: Nope, these logs say nothing. Try enable debug by changing `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php` file and post what you get on the browser.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but my browser says nothing other than "This site cannot be reached. The connection was reset." That's what makes it so frustrating--I can't interact with the site at all.

Comment: If your site set up as virtual host, make sure you have set up it [properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your continued efforts. I know the site was set up properly because I used it for a week or more, logging in and out as normal. This will sound naive, I know (I'm a lifelong software guy): But "I didn't change anything" the night that it stopped working. I finally just gave up and reinstalled wordpress with an import of an old backup. That route cost less time. Best regards, Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally gave up, reinstalled wordpress, and imported an old backup of the site. I lost a tiny bit of work (my backup was recent), but in total it was far less work than trying to debug the failed site.

One of the biggest problems with a "Connection reset" error is that you can't easily interact with the site through a browser. Unless you know exactly what the problem is under the hood (I didn't know), and know exactly what system / wordpress files to change (I didn't know), debugging is impossible.

I'm answering this question and closing it so that others might benefit from my experience, and reinstall their own failed site before wasting too much time like I did.