# How can I make Codeigniter session work with edge?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies, microsoft-edge

I checked for the session cookie in edge and it was not available. In chrome, the session cookie works fine. I tried both php superglobal  `$_SESSION[]` and the magic getter `$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);` while setting session

Here are the session config values:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cekosessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'cekosessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Here are the cookie config values:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = 'ncitce';
$config['cookie_domain'] = 'localhost';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: try Using vhost for project.

Comment: And to get codeigniter session after has been set `echo $this->session->userdata('user_id')`

Comment: Have no idea on vhost. Tried getting vhost to run but didn't work. Will look on that later. I'm in kind of hurry. Anyway, thanks. I think I figured out something with your mention of vhost.

Comment: vHost is where you can use a dummy domain on your xampp wamp etc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=virtual+host+xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, All my CodeIgniter 3 projects work fine in Edge. Please try this configuration in config.php file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

and

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Remember to create ci_session table in your database.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

If above method failed please comment below.

Comment: Yeah, if failed. But, I created vhost and everything works fine. Looks like edge didn't want to create cookie for localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a lower codeigniter version, you can replace the Session class of CI with this class, which stores session data on the server:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dariusz-Debowczyk%27s-Session-Class

Also see this link for a discussion:
https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/135722/codeigniter-session-problems-thread