# virtualhost not working. xammp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am trying to setup my virtualhost in xammp. But it is redrecting to google search.
i have modified following file:
host:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       lanedain.localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

httpd-conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
       ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lanedain/public"
ServerName lanedain.localhost
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/lanedain/public">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you restarted XAMPP?

Comment: Probably you need dns flush ( ``ipconfig /flushdns`` ) and for chrome you can clear dns cache from here  ``chrome://net-internals/#dns``

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain yes i did restart my xammp

Comment: @MehmetSoylu i tried flushing dns. it is still not working

Comment: @SarbanThapaMagar you can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp

Comment: can you try ``VirtualHost *:80`` for second virtualhost ``VirtualHost lanedain.localhost:80``

Comment: problem has been solved. thanks for help.