# Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network without URL changing

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost, lan

I have already read [Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to), but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have setup custom domain(virtual host like [how to create virtual host on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp)). The local IP of this PC is 192.168.1.9 and I access to it using http://sample.test.

Now I am on another PC and it local IP addresses is 192.168.1.8. How to access http://sample.test via this PC? Is it possible to configure this pc to access to the site just using http://sample.test because URL changes(Starting URL with IP Address) break the site.

Update : I am on Windows 10 PC

Comment: Try changing the windows host file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts open as administrator) on the 192.168.1.8 pc and add this line.
192.168.1.9 sample.com
and save it

Comment: What kind of operating system you are using (Mac, Linux, Windows,...)? On Mac or Linux operating system you need to edit the /etc/hosts file with root privileges and add at the end what @NickZulu suggested.

Comment: @sys0dm1n Updated the post

Answer (score -1):

As you are on a Windows 10 PC try editing your Windows hostfile, found at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` adding the line
`192.168.1.9       sample.test`

Answer (score -1):

Edit host file in your client computer (Windows 10), it's located on
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc.

Add the ip and virtual domain like this and then save the file, you might have to run your text editor as administrator.

## ======= My Web App =======

127.0.0.1       localhost

192.168.1.9     sample.test