# After installing xampp & wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, localhost

When i was trying to access after installation of wordpress "localhost/wordpress" it shows Error 404 not found & along with that error it shows:
Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.7 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Where have you installed your wordpress ? Path ?

Comment: F:\wordpress...... the path is like this

Comment: Well if you have just installed XAMPP you should know that the host file is at : `www` folder inside your xampp installation in C. You should put all your contents inside that. If you want to use `F:\wordpress` you will have to change confs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27268267/8298248 this should help with that.