# Multiple xampp uses single php environment variable problem

Tags: php, laravel, windows, xampp, environment-variables

I have installed two xampp in my windows 11 machine. One is in c:/xampp and another one is in E:/xampp but the environment variable that I have been using is taking the php version from E:/xampp/php. I would like to run lower version of laravel application with older php version 7 in C:/xampp and new laravel development I would like to use the E:/xampp with latest php version 8. Is there a way in which The xampp in C can use only the php from c:/xampp and the xampp in E can only use the php from E:/xampp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)

Comment: Quick fast solution for me was to keep Environment path same, i just switch content in php folder

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI in laravel the composer will not identify the php version we are mentioning in the composer.json. It won't work even if the single xampp has multiple php in it. I have set up my second xampp according to the link you have mentioned. but it is not working.

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa As you have mentioned about environment variable. i checked with 'where php' command in my terminal and it clearly took the php version from the xampp i have installed in my E:/ drive. So i set another environment variable  there and set the php path to C:/ drive xampp. So now there are two environment vars when i run the 'where php' in terminal. But still my laravel app composer update uses the php 8 from the E:/xampp/php. But in my C:/xampp/php i have the php version 7 which i want to use to avoid the php error: 'getClass() is deprecated' .

Comment: @jeenus I keep the only one ENV path for php, which point to one `php` directory, and only one xampp, just replace whole php folder content with another content (cut/paste work to remove one version and place another). and that was quickies way to switch php versions with one xampp

Answer (score 0):

> Best way is to make virtual host and defile both project paths in virtual host.
> like abc.com for a project in C directory project and xyz.com for E directory project.
> in this way you will run xamp that will automatically map project for its url defined in virtual host configurations.

[you can get proper guideline from here in this link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

With [Deverser](https://www.easyphp.org) and his Virtual Host Manager you can do whatever you want. You can define a specific environment for each one.