# Way to open localhost with different URL

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have tried `http://localhost/projectname` and `http://127.0.0.1/project_name` to open my Project in **LocalHost**

but

I want to open this with some other URL so user can not able to know that I have opened with `localhost`.

#### Edited:

> My Users currently accessing my project with `localhost` but now i
>   want to use some static string to open as url. I mean if currently
>   users accessing project with `localhost/proj` but i want to do like
>   `staticString/proj` Is it possible?

Is there any way to open project with different URL rather than `localhost`?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Where is your project hosted? Who are your users? How do they access your project now? It's like "How do I go home if I don't want the people visiting me them to know I'm where I am?"

Comment: I have users offline, and they accessing project `localhost` but dont want to do like that. I simply want to use another keywords to open that project rather than `localhost`

Comment: `projectname` seems like your project. `localhost` is not a project, it is a server name. The server name of the current computer, to be specific. It is your computer's word for "myself". If your users are offline, their `localhost` is always going to be different than your `localhost`. I still have no idea what you want, or how your users are currently accessing your project.

Comment: My Users currently accessing my project with `localhost` but now i want to use some static string to open as url. I mean if currently users accessing project with `localhost/proj` but i want to do like `staticString/proj` Is it possible.

Comment: Unless your users are sitting at your keyboard, or have your project installed on their own computer, it is *impossible* for them to access your project on `localhost` if they are offline as you claim. Something here does not add up. If you are all not in fact offline, and are sharing a server together, then you can find your server's IP and use that instead, or even register a DNS domain to that IP and use *that*. But it will *not work* offline.

Comment: @Amadan See this is what i like http://stackoverflow.com/a/27633340/1318946

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981174/apache-virtualhost-and-localhost Please refer this link @PratikButani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Configure first Virtual Host in your XAMPP or any Web server.
After you can use that name instead of Localhost or IP Address.

Follow this link to configure Virtual Host.

http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

and this also

http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php

Answer (score 3):

- You can make use of virtual host configuration in your web server.
- Edit your hosts file to include 127.0.0.1    thisismyhost.com

Then can should be able to access your project using thisismyhost.com/my_project

Answer (score 1):

I follow solution of accepted answer but I found one tricky Magic solution for that which i can use without any configuration:

You can use ***yourString.google*** It will directly open you localhost.

For Example: Open this link in your browser: **[pratik.google/](http://pratik.google/)**

if you have installed `xampp` it will open your `localhost`

Really amazing magical trick.

I don't know how it works, May be this is functionality of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is local tunnel

Use node and npm to install it globally using `npm install -g localtunnel`

then give the port you want to export `lt --port <port>`

you will get a link you can share anywhere and anyone can access your localhost site. there are multiple ways and options to it. you can view about it - [here](http://localtunnel.me/)!

Answer (score 0):

if you change the port you will see the result like this

```
> http://localhost:5906/projectname/abc.aspx
```

right click on the project click on properties and there will be one option web in that change the specific port

hope this may help

Comment: But i dont want to use keyword like `localhost`