# Vhost and add CSS

Tags: html, css, macos, apache, vhosts

I created vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Almond/Sites/Projet1/web"
    ServerName local.dev
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory /Users/Almond/Sites/Projet1/web>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I can't bind my style css, when I put in my head of page html like link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

On my browser the style css doesn't work, I tell me that the link is `local.dev/style.css`

So I don't understand that I do modifies.

Comment: Where in the file system are your HTML file and this stylesheet located?

Comment: Hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981174/apache-virtualhost-and-localhost

Comment: So my stylesheet is in web/css/style.css my structure is 

- app
- src -> Views -> templates -> default.html 
- vendor
- web -> css -> style.css